# VBA Parsing XML nested nodes

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I am new to parsing XML files in Excel VBA.  From other forums & answers I've been able to put the following VBA Code together to parse elements out of the XML file and put them on the Excel sheet.  However in various nodes of the XML file, a text field is broken into parts and assigned sequence numbers.

The following code parses the XML fields (one row per record). Can someone show me how to retrieve all the text parts not just the first one?

Secondly, the parts of the text fields are not always in sequential order. Can the parts be re-assembled in sequence number order?

Here is my notional XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    -<Station>
    -<Action>
    <ID>A001</ID>
    <Type>AS</Type>
    <ActionDescInfo>
      <Sequence>01</Sequence>
      <Desc>Text block one.</Desc>
    </ActionDescInfo>
    </Action>
    -<Action>
    <ID>A002</ID>
    <Type>AP</Type>
    <ActionDescInfo>
      <Sequence>01</Sequence>
      <Desc>Another text block</Desc>
      <Sequence>02</Sequence>
      <Desc>Text following first one</Desc>
    </ActionDescInfo>
    </Action>
    -<Action>
    <ID>A003</ID>
    <Type>AS</Type>
    <ActionDescInfo>
      <Sequence>03</Sequence>
      <Desc>This comes third and is out of place</Desc>
      <Sequence>01</Sequence>
      <Desc>this one is first</Desc>
      <Sequence>02</Sequence>
      <Desc>This text is second. But all the same paragraph</Desc>
    </ActionDescInfo>
    </Action>
    </Station>
```

Here is the Code so far:

```
    Sub XMLShare()
    'Public Sub Xml_To_Excel()
    Dim osh As Worksheet
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Dim xmlDoc As Object
    Dim nodeXML1 As Object
    Dim nodeXML2 As Object
    Dim nodeXML3 As Object
    Dim nodeXML4 As Object
    Dim i As Integer, oRow As Integer
    ' Clear Sheet
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
     Cells.Select
     Selection.Clear
    ' Variables
     oRow = 1
    ' Sets
    Set osh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load ("filename.xml")
    Set nodeXML1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ID")
    Set nodeXML2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Type")
    Set nodeXML3 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Sequence")
    Set nodeXML4 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Desc")
    ' Processing Loop
      For i =0 To nodeXML1.Length - 1
        oRow = oRow + 1
       osh.Range("A" & oRow) = nodeXML1(i).Text        ' ID
       osh.Range("B" & oRow) = nodeXML2(i).Text    ' Type
       osh.Range("C" & oRow) = nodeXML3(i).Text    ' Sequence
       osh.Range("D" & oRow) = nodeXML4(i).Text    ' Desc
      Next
    ' Finish
        MsgBox "Process Completed"
    End Sub
```

This is my desired outcome:

```
    ID  Type    Desc
    001 AS  Text block one.
    002 AP  Another text block that follows the first one.
    003 AS  This one is first. This text is second. But all the
                    same paragraph. This comes third and is out of place.
```

Comment: What version of Excel?  If 2016, read up about the `WEBSERVICE` and `FILTERXML` functions.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution. First of all, you need to use the ActionDescInfo as node. In that node, you can use a new loop to loop through all the sequence and desc elements. Use an array wherein you can set the right sequence:

```
Sub XMLShare()
    'Public Sub Xml_To_Excel()'
    Dim osh As Worksheet
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Dim xmlDoc As Object
    Dim nodeXML1 As Object
    Dim nodeXML2 As Object
    Dim nodeXML3 As Object
    Dim nodeXML4 As Object
    Dim i As Integer, oRow As Integer
    Dim SequenceArr() As String
    Dim DescArr() As String
    ' Clear Sheet'
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Clear
    ' Variables'
     oRow = 1
    ' Sets'
    Set osh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.SetProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load ("C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\test.xml")
    Set nodeXML1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ID")
    Set nodeXML2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Type")
    Set nodeXML3 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ActionDescInfo")
    Set nodeXML4 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Desc")
    ' Processing Loop'
    For i = 0 To nodeXML1.Length - 1
        x = 0
        oRow = oRow + 1
        osh.Range("A" & oRow) = nodeXML1(i).Text        ' ID'
        osh.Range("B" & oRow) = nodeXML2(i).Text    ' Type'
        'Loop through the childnodes of ActionDescInfo'
        For j = 0 To nodeXML3(i).ChildNodes.Length - 1
            'If the childnode is sequence, find out the order and put the values in an array'
            If nodeXML3(i).ChildNodes(j).BaseName = "Sequence" Then
                'if x = 0, the cell is empty and just fill the first element of the array'
                'Else, loop through each element in the array to check if the number is larger or smaller'
                If x > 0 Then
                    For k = 0 To UBound(SequenceArr)
                        'If the value in the array is larger, this is the element where the new sequence number needs to be filled in'
                        If SequenceArr(k) > nodeXML3(i).ChildNodes(j).Text Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next k
                Else
                    k = 0
                End If
                'Move all elements one up and put the sequence number on the right place'
                ReDim Preserve SequenceArr(x)
                For l = k To UBound(SequenceArr) - 1
                    SequenceArr(l + 1) = SequenceArr(l)
                Next l
                SequenceArr(k) = nodeXML3(i).ChildNodes(j).Text
                x = x + 1
            'If the childnode is the description, do the same as for the sequence: Put the value in the array on the same place as the previous sequence number'
            ElseIf nodeXML3(i).ChildNodes(j).BaseName = "Desc" Then
                ReDim Preserve DescArr(x)
                For l = k To UBound(DescArr) - 1
                    DescArr(l + 1) = DescArr(l)
                Next l
                DescArr(k) = nodeXML3(i).ChildNodes(j).Text
            End If
        Next j
        'Put the array values in the right cells'
        For j = 0 To UBound(SequenceArr)
            osh.Range("C" & oRow).Value = osh.Range("C" & oRow).Value & " " & SequenceArr(j)
            osh.Range("D" & oRow).Value = osh.Range("D" & oRow).Value & " " & DescArr(j)
        Next j
        'Erase the arrays again for the next iteration'
        Erase SequenceArr
        Erase DescArr
    Next i
' Finish'
MsgBox "Process Completed"
End Sub
```

I don't know if this is the fastest way, but I checked and it works. Also I hope you can understand my comments. English is not my first language.